# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'setZIndex')

Tags: reactjs, leaflet, react-leaflet

I'm trying to add aeronautical info to my leaflet map and I had to extend the leaflet tile layer function to allow for an apiKey to be passed as a query parameter. My code works when I try adding the layer directly to the map; however, I would like the option to have it as a controlled layer. Whenever I try adding it to the layer control, I get the error in the title.

```
export default function AeroInfo() {
    const map = useMap();

    L.TileLayer.Aeronautical = L.TileLayer.extend({
        getTileUrl: function (coords) {
            return "https://api.tiles.openaip.net/api/data/openaip/" + coords.z + "/" + coords.x + "/" + coords.y + ".png?apiKey=APIKEYGOESHERE";
        },
    });

    L.tileLayer.aeroInfo = function () {
        return new L.TileLayer.Aeronautical();
    }

    // L.tileLayer.aeroInfo().addTo(map);

    L.control.layers(null,L.tileLayer.aeroInfo()).addTo(map);
    return null;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to put the layer into `{}`:

```
L.control.layers(null,{ info: L.tileLayer.aeroInfo() }).addTo(map);
```

**Edit:**

Adding multiple layers to an control:

```
var layers = {
   info: L.tileLayer.aeroInfo(),
   otherLayer: L.tileLayer.aeroInfo()
};
L.control.layers(null, layers).addTo(map);
```

or after creation:

```
var layerControl = L.control.layers(null, layers).addTo(map);

layerControl.addOverlay(L.tileLayer.aeroInfo(), "name");
```

Comment: Thank you very much! I now have another issues though. I have another layer control set up in a map container, but when I add the aeroInfo to the layer control in this file, two layer control icons pop up on the map. Is there a way to add aeroInfo to the exisiting layer control?

Comment: @OutStrike I updated the answer. Please also look into the [docu](https://leafletjs.com/reference.html#control-layers)